# Is there an easy method to read an external web page's source code? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Id like to be able to write a function that reads an external news site and returns the source code of the target page.  Any ideas and/or information to get me started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string GetOtherPage(System.Uri url)
{
    return new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: this one-liner should'nt be one-liner ;)

    string content;
    using(var wc = new WebClient()){
      content = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
    return content;

Comment: Nah: if there's an exception or something it will still be disposed right away because of the scope block created by the function.

Comment: I didn't know that c# with it's GC was applying the RAII idiom. I thought it would do for (stack allocated) struct but not for full fledged classes. I'm going to check this.

Comment: I doubt it follows that 'idiom' exactly: it's more a practical thing: if the exception is unhandled the program and all it's resources are cleaned up anyway.  If it is handled, then it's just as good as if the function executed normally, and with no references to the object it can be GC'd.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class and the sample

But please, don't make such *crappy* code as MSDN sample yourself, use the [using](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/the_very_handy_using_statement.aspx) idiom where appropriate

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the HTML source, then Joel's answer is correct.

However, if you are talking about the actual codebehind for dynamic pages, the answer is "thankfully, no".  Most properly configured sites will not return the source code that is dynamically executed to make a page.

Comment: yeah its just reading the rendered page, not the code behind.